# Statements falling through to the next line

Tags: java

For some reason my statement keeps going through to the next line without doing what it is supposed to.

```
package Employee;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;



public class EmployeeTest {

public static void main (String args[]) {

out.println ("Welcome to employee storer: ");

Scanner imput = new Scanner (System.in);
Employee employee1 = new Employee();// Creates an employee
Employee employee2 = new Employee();

out.println ("Please enter first name: ");
String fName = imput.nextLine(); //reads keyboard
    employee1.setfName(fName);// sets first name

out.println("please enter last name: ");
String lName = imput.nextLine();//reads keyboard
    employee1.setlName(lName);// sets second name

out.println("Please enter pay: ");
double pay = imput.nextDouble();//reads keyboard
    employee1.setPay(pay);//sets the pay

out.println ("Please enter first name: ");
String fName1 = imput.nextLine(); //reads keyboard
    employee2.setfName(fName1);// sets first name

out.println("please enter last name: ");
String lName1 = imput.nextLine();//reads keyboard
    employee2.setlName(lName1);// sets second name

out.println("Please enter pay: ");
double pay1 = imput.nextDouble();//reads keyboard
    employee2.setPay(pay1);//sets the pay

employee1.printer();// prints the info
employee2.printer();// same here

employee1.raise();
}
```

}

My problem is the second fName imput, it never gets an input from the console, it ends up looking like this

```
"Welcome to employee storer: 
 Please enter first name: 
 Jake
 please enter last name: 
 Smith
 Please enter pay: 
 100
 Please enter first name: 
 please enter last name: 
 Jake
 Please enter pay: 
 100
 The employee Jake Smith yearly salary is: 1200.0
 The employee Jake yearly salary is: 1200.0
 Your raise is: 120.0
 Your new yearly pay is: 1200.0120.0"
```

My method class looks like this:
    package Employee;
    import static java.lang.System.out;

```
public class Employee {
private String fName;
private String lName;
private double pay;

public void payCheck() {
    if (pay > 0 )
        pay = 0;
}
public double yearly() {
    double overall = pay * 12; 
    return overall;
}
public void printer() {
    out.println( " The employee " + fName + " " + lName + 
            " yearly salary is: " + pay * 12 );
}
public void raise() {
    double year = pay * 12;
    double increase = .1;
    double raise = increase * year;
    out.println("Your raise is: " + raise );
    out.print("Your new yearly pay is: " + year + raise);
}


// Getters and setters 
public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}
public void setfName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}
public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}
public void setlName(String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}
public double getPay() {
    return pay;
}
public void setPay(double pay) {
    this.pay = pay;
}
```

}

I also get an odd output for the final yearly pay. Not really sure why, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the love of god refactor 'imput' to 'input' instead of leaving 200 spelling mistakes in your code before showing it to the public here...

Comment: @Niels (I thought the same thing; however, I think it's on purpose...)

Comment: It does not matter for the hardcore programming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
imput.nextDouble();
```

just execute below line after `nextDouble();`

```
imput.nextLine();
```

whenever you want to Scan numbers with a `.next()` call, make sure you add an empty `.nextLine()` next to it so that the `Scanner` moves to the correct position

Answer (score 5):

`nextDouble()` will return only the `Double` value on the line, leaving the line return behind, which is picked up by the next `nextLine()` statement.

Answer (score 2):

nextDouble() just reads a double from the input, not a double on an entire line. The carriage return you entered after the double remains in the input, which is immediately retrieved by the nextLine() statement after, not halting.

Retrieve it with nextLine() as for all the others, then convert the result to a double (with errorchecking obviously).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're pressing enter after the double; System.in is getting a double followed by a newline, which gets read as a double (the newline stops the scanning) then tries to read a string up to new line (which results in an empty string)

Answer (score 1):

Also about the last part of your question

```
out.print("Your new yearly pay is: " + year + raise);
```

This is doing simple string concatenation, so you get "strange" result. Instead, try an extra pair of brackets for proper summation and then concatenation

```
out.print("Your new yearly pay is: " + (year + raise));
```